# JSON binding to multiple tables on one page

Tags: html, json, data-binding

I have  a web page will display documents for modules, each module is documented in a separate table, as following

```
<div role="main">
<div class="section">
<h2 id="acces_extranet">Acces_Extranet</h2>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nom</th>
<th>Commentaire</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td />
<td />
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<h3 id="connexion_extranet">Connexion_Extranet</h3>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nom</th>
<th>Commentaire</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td />
<td />
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<h4 id="m00_0_lancer_navigateur">M00_0_Lancer_Navigateur</h4>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Variables</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>navigateur</td>
<td>Insérer description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>url</td>
<td>Insérer description</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

in the other hand i have a CSV file that i transformed to JSON file, i want to read data from this file to display them permanently in my HTML page.

```
[
  {
 "Module": "M00_0_Lancer_Navigateur",
 "Variable": "navigateur",
 "Description": "Le navigateur à utiliser pour le test, non sensible à la case",
 "Valeurs": "",
 "": ""
  },
  {
 "Module": "M00_0_Lancer_Navigateur",
 "Variable": "url",
 "Description": "l'url initiale du site à lancer, il peut s'agir d'une url ARIANE ou magie de tout environnement",
 "Valeurs": "",
 "": ""
  },
  {
 "Module": "M00_2_Extranet_Connexion",
 "Variable": "login",
 "Description": "Insérer description",
 "Valeurs": "",
 "": ""
  }
]
```

I want to display data in tables from the JSON file?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using PHP? You can use PHP to `json_decode(json_text)` to give you an array of the keys and values. You can incorporate a for loop to print a row

for example......

```
<?php 

$raw_json = file_get_contents($path_to_json);
$json_data = json_decode($raw_json); // $json_data is now an array of the json data 

?>


<?php foreach($json_data as $row){ ?>
    <tr> <?php echo $row['key'] ?></tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I want to use jquery or angularjs, because my file is generated from markdown files.